# How to declare typings included in library in tsconfig?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I get the following message in VSCode.:

> Could not find a declaration file for module `'LIBRARY'`.
> `'...node_modules/LIBRARY/lib/FILENAME.js'` implicitly has an `'any'`
> type.   Try `npm install @types/LIBRARY` if it exists or add a new
> declaration (`.d.ts`) file containing `declare module 'LIBRARY';`ts(7016)

I have declared a (.d.ts) file in the `typings` folder in `node_modules/LIBRARY/`.

Also I use [LocalForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) as a dependency in my `LIBRARY`. LocalForage brings their own typings in `node_modules/localforage/typings/ localforage.d.ts`, which can also not be found.

I tried the following in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
.
.
.
    "types": [
      "**/*.d.ts",
      "./node_modules/localforage/typings/localforage.d.ts",
      "./node_modules/LIBRARY/typings/FILENAME.d.ts",
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/*/typings",
      "./node_modules/**/typings",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
.
.
.
}
```

but it does not work.

How can I setup it in the `tsconfig` file, so that Typescript can find it?

Comment: Remove the file from the `typings` subdirectory and name it `index.d.ts`.

Comment: I can only do that for my own library, but not for the dependency [`localForage`](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) of my library

Comment: Why did you say that _you_ declared typings for it then? It comes with them

Comment: Because it also concerns my own declared typings. I will update my question to clarify that.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE did you find out how to do it?